# Control flow in recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

I want to understand the control flow in the recursive function.

I have written a recursive function for calculating prime factors of a number. But it is not giving the correct output. I know that compiler uses stack data structure to handle the execution of functions and the values evaluated by the functions.
But the output of this code has confused me. I do not understand how the control is flowing from the recursive call of the function.
I have used @ and # signs to understand which `printf()` statement gets executed during runtime.
Also, the following code is not giving the correct output. Please help me correct the error in the following code.

```
    /* Recursive function to calculate prime factors of a number */

    #include<stdio.h>

    int rec(unsigned);

    int main()
    {
      unsigned n;
      printf("Enter a number: ");
      scanf("%ud", &n);
      rec(n);
      return 0;
    }

    int rec(unsigned n)
    {
      int i, j;
      for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
      {
        for(j=2; j<i; j++)
        {
          if(i%j==0)
            break;
        }
        if(i==j)
        {
          if(n%i==0)
          {
            n /= i;
            if(n==1) //ONE IF
            {
              printf("%d@ ", i);
              //Substitute this with return 1; for 2nd set of output
            }
            else
            {
              printf("%d# ", i);
              rec(n); //Recursive call
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The above code gives the following output for the respective input:-

1. For n=6, Output: 2# 3@ 3@
2. For n=12, Output: 2# 2# 3@ 3@ 3# 2@
3. For n=20, Output: 2# 2# 5@ 5@ 5# 2@

If I substitute ONE IF's `printf()` statement with `return 1;` then I have
the following output:-

1. For n=6, Output: 2#
2. For n=12, Output: 2# 2# 3#
3. For n=20, Output: 2# 2# 5#

Please help me understand the control flow in both the situations.
Thank you.

> EDIT: I have found the correct code which gives the correct output. We
>   have to change the code written in the `if(i==j)` statement:

```
if(i==j)
{
  if(n%i==0)
  {
    printf("%d# ", i);
    rec(n/i);
    break;
  }
}
```

> Following is the output:-
>
> 1. For n=6, Output: 2# 3#
> 2. For n=12, Output: 2# 2# 3#
> 3. For n=20, Output: 2# 2# 5#
> 4. For n=5, Output: 5#
> 5. For n=16, Output: 2# 2# 2# 2#
>
> Hence, the question of correcting the code has been solved. But still the problem of control flow in recursive calling of function has not been solved.
>   Also, here the return type of the function should be changed from `int` to `void` as `rec()` does not need to return anything.

Comment: C and C++ are completely different languages. Please only tag one (unless your question actually concerns both, which it doesn't appear to here).

Comment: Which C++ book claims that a recursive algorithm is required to find prime numbers? The two simply don't go together. The shown algorithm is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: When you make a statement like `rec(n);` and it returns a number, you are jus throwing that number away. Everytime you get to `rec(n)` you start a completely new call that has **nothing** to do with the previous one. They act independently and the first one waits for the secon one to finish before it continues its loop. It's the same with `printf("%d# ", i);`. No matter how much recursion there is in the implementation of `printf` your program just waits until it has done its job and printed out something before it continues on the line after and `printf`. Recursive functions aren't special.

Comment: @Sylwester Why is that a comment? Wouldn't it have been easier to write that into an answer?

Comment: Your `rec` never returns anything.  Why is it declared to return `int`?

Comment: @scohe001 I am sorry to include the C++ tag. Thanks for reminding

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I did not refer to any book in the question. Nor I want to ask about any book. I just want to know about the control flow in recursion. I have not used any algorithm from the book. And once again, I just want to know how the control flows during recursive function calling

Comment: @DavisHerring You are right in pointing out the return type of this function. I wrote the return type as int because I have said to substitute the printf() in ONE IF with return 1; statement. That's why I wrote return type as int.

Comment: @Sylwester Thank you for answering the question. Will you please write the answer in detail? It will be really helpful if you will explain the answer in steps. Using diagrams will clear the concept of recursion clearly. Please explain both sets of output. Thank you.

Comment: `%ud` is nonsense

Comment: @AnttiHaapala If I write %ud instead of %u then also the compiler doesn't give any error. I was checking whether it is valid or not. Also, please answer the question about control flow of recursive function.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at recursive calls of a function `rec()` as if you have enough functions `rec_1()`, `rec_2()`, ..., `ren_n()`, all with the same lines in them but the next function called. `rec_1()` calls `rec_2()` if needed, which in turn calls `rec_3()` if needed, and so on.

As @Sylwester pointed out, each `rec()` calling itself is "waiting" at the call site until the called `rec()` returns. And each of the `rec()` has its own set of parameters and local variables. BTW, you could look at parameters as local variables to the called function that are initialized with the caller's arguments.

You will see the control flow more clearly if you put more `printf()` in your source, like this for your initial code:

```
int level = 0;
int rec(unsigned n)
{
  int i, j;
  level++;
  printf("rec(%u) at level %d STARTS\n", n, level);
  for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
  /* other lines cut for brevity */
          printf("rec(...) at level %d found %d, IS CALLING rec(%u):\n", level, i, n); /* was: printf("%d# ", i); */
          rec(n); //Recursive call
          printf("rec(...) at level %d CONTINUES after calling rec(%u):\n", level, n);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  printf("rec(...) at level %d RETURNS\n", level);
  level--;
}
```

For the corrected code it will be:

```
if(n%i==0)
{
  printf("rec(...) at level %d found %d, IS CALLING rec(%u):\n", level, i, n/i); /* was: printf("%d# ", i); */
  rec(n/i);
  printf("rec(...) at level %d CONTINUES after calling rec(%u):\n", level, n/i);
  break;
}
```